# Error when trying to fit Hierarchical GAMs (Model GS or S) using mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have a large dataset (~100k observations) of presence/absence data that I am trying to fit a Hierarchical GAM with individual effects that have a Shared penalty (e.g. 'S' in Pedersen et al. 2019). The data consists of temp as numeric, region (5 groups) as a factor.
Here is a simple version of the model that I am trying to fit.

```
modS1 <- gam(occurrence ~ s(temp, region), family = binomial,
             data = df, method = "REML")

modS2 <- gam(occurrence ~ s(temp, region, k= c(10,4), family = binomial,
             data = df, method = "REML")
```

In the first case I received the following error:
Which I assumed it because k was set too high for region given there are only 5 different regions in the data set.

> Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> 2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

In the second case I attempt to lower k for region and receive this error:

> Error in if (k < M + 1) { : the condition has length > 1
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> 2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

I can fit Models G and GI and I from Pedersen et al. 2019 with no issues. It is models GS and S where I run into issues.

If anyone has any insights I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @GregorThomas In Pedersen et al. they provide example code where this model was fit. CO2_modS <- gam(log(uptake) ∼ s(log(conc), Plant_uo, k=5, bs="fs", m=2), data=CO2, method="REML")
Where Plant_uo is an unordered factor. I believe my code is similar to this. In response to the second comment based on my understanding, the first example would be a global smooth (model G) averaged over regions and the second would be group specific smoothers with different wigglyness (model I) which are not the same and differ from what I am trying to fit above

Comment: @aczich Yeah, sorry about that. In R version 4.0, the R Code Team decided to switch the long-standing default `stringsAsFactors` to be FALSE. I think we do mention that categorical vars have to be coded as factors in the paper, but the code examples we showed didn't explicitly convert these to factors as that was implied in versions of R < 4.0. Now you would need to explicitly convert variables to be factors in our code examples

Comment: @aczich but also your code *isn't* similar to ours; What seems like an innocuous change (deleting `bs = "fs"`) is fundamentally changing the basis you are using from a random univariate smooth basis, with smooths for each level of the factor but with shared smoothing parameter for all smooths, to a isotropic 2D thin-plate regression spline basis. The `bs = "fs"` bit is really important, as is my point about now having to explicitly code character vectors as factors since the R default changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bs = "fs"` argument in the code you're using as a guide is important. If we start at the `?s` help page and click on the link to the `?smooth.terms` help page, we see:

> Factor smooth interactions
>
> `bs="fs"` Smooth factor interactions are often produced using by variables (see `gam.models`), but a special smoother class (see `factor.smooth.interaction`) is available for the case in which a smooth is required at each of a large number of factor levels (for example a smooth for each patient in a study), and each smooth should have the same smoothing parameter. The `"fs"` smoothers are set up to be efficient when used with `gamm`, and have penalties on each null space component (i.e. they are fully ‘random effects’).

You need to use a smoothing basis appropriate for factors.

Notably, if you take your source code and remove the `bs = "fs"` argument and attempt to run `gam(log(uptake) ∼ s(log(conc), Plant_uo, k=5, m=2), data=CO2, method="REML")`, it will produce the same error that you got.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you! I somehow didn't even realize that was different, but that makes a lot of sense.